# How can I use a loop to apply a function to a list of csv files?

Tags: pandas, function, csv, for-loop, data-manipulation

I'm trying to loop through all files in a directory and add "indicator" data to them. I had the code working where I could select 1 file and do this, but now am trying to make it work on all files. The problem is when I make the loop it says

`ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>`

The goal would be for each loop to read another file from list, make changes, and save file back to folder with changes.

Here is complete code w/o imports. I copied 1 of the "file_path"s from the list and put in comment at bottom.

```
### open dialog to select file
#file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

###create list from dir
listdrs = os.listdir('c:/Users/17409/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Indicators/Sentdex Tutorial/stock_dfs/')

###append full path to list
string = 'c:/Users/17409/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Indicators/Sentdex Tutorial/stock_dfs/'
listdrs_path = [ string + x for x in listdrs]
print (listdrs_path)

###start loop, for each "file" in listdrs run the 2 functions below and overwrite saved csv.
for file in listdrs_path:
    file_path = listdrs_path

    data = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=0)


    ########################################
    ####function 1
    def get_price_hist(ticker):


        # Put stock price data in dataframe
        data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        #listdr = os.listdir('Users\17409\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Indicators\Sentdex Tutorial\stock_dfs')
        print(listdr)
        # Convert date to timestamp and make index
        data.index = data["Date"].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x))
        data.drop("Date", axis=1, inplace=True)

        return data


    df = data
    ##print(data)

    ######Indicator data#####################

    def get_indicators(data):
        # Get MACD
        data["macd"], data["macd_signal"], data["macd_hist"] = talib.MACD(data['Close'])

        # Get MA10 and MA30
        data["ma10"] = talib.MA(data["Close"], timeperiod=10)
        data["ma30"] = talib.MA(data["Close"], timeperiod=30)

        # Get RSI
        data["rsi"] = talib.RSI(data["Close"])
        return data
    #####end functions#######





data2 = get_indicators(data)
print(data2)
data2.to_csv(file_path)

###################################################

#here is an example of what path from list looks like
#'c:/Users/17409/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Indicators/Sentdex Tutorial/stock_dfs/A.csv'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in line number 13 and 14. Your filename is in variable `file` but you are using `file_path` which you've assigned the file list. Because of this you are getting `ValueError`. Try this:

```
### open dialog to select file
#file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()

###create list from dir
listdrs = os.listdir('c:/Users/17409/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Indicators/Sentdex Tutorial/stock_dfs/')

###append full path to list
string = 'c:/Users/17409/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Indicators/Sentdex Tutorial/stock_dfs/'
listdrs_path = [ string + x for x in listdrs]
print (listdrs_path)

###start loop, for each "file" in listdrs run the 2 functions below and overwrite saved csv.
for file_path in listdrs_path:

    data = pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col=0)


    ########################################
    ####function 1
    def get_price_hist(ticker):


        # Put stock price data in dataframe
        data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        #listdr = os.listdir('Users\17409\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Indicators\Sentdex Tutorial\stock_dfs')
        print(listdr)
        # Convert date to timestamp and make index
        data.index = data["Date"].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(x))
        data.drop("Date", axis=1, inplace=True)

        return data


    df = data
    ##print(data)

    ######Indicator data#####################

    def get_indicators(data):
        # Get MACD
        data["macd"], data["macd_signal"], data["macd_hist"] = talib.MACD(data['Close'])

        # Get MA10 and MA30
        data["ma10"] = talib.MA(data["Close"], timeperiod=10)
        data["ma30"] = talib.MA(data["Close"], timeperiod=30)

        # Get RSI
        data["rsi"] = talib.RSI(data["Close"])
        return data
    #####end functions#######





data2 = get_indicators(data)
print(data2)
data2.to_csv(file_path)
```

Let me know if it helps.